# mysql - return first column once and all corresponding column data

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure if the title really defines what I'm looking for.

What I want to do is return all rows that have a matching column value. Display the first value only once, and display all other columns. Here's a visual of the table:

```
id     name    data
======================
0      john    data1
1      john    data2
2      jane    data1
3      jane    data2
4      jane    data3
```

So the result would be displayed as:

```
john
  data1
  data2

jane
  data1
  data2
  data3
```

I know I can use `DISTINCT` to get the name once, but would I need to get all names from a query first, then do a loop and run a second query, or can I do this in one statement?

Right now I have a `foreach` that uses an array to loop through and get everything. So it currently displays as:

```
john - data1
john - data2
jane - data1
jane - data2
jane - data3
```

It just seems aesthetically bad to show the first column every time, but I'm not too sure how to go about this efficiently.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The way the SQL query returns results is just sort of how it is - SQL will return a 2D data set, where each row bears no relation to the rows surrounding it.  What you are asking for is really the domain of your output formatting, not to be done in the SQL query. If you post your PHP code used for writing out these results, we can suggest how to modify it for your desired presentation.

Comment: Do this in PHP, not MySQL. Have your loop check whether the name is the same as the previous row. Only display the name header when it changes.

Comment: This isn't how SQL works.  The control break logic used for displaying the column should be in the presentation layer not the data layer.

Comment: Typically in your output loop, you store the last value of that column in a variable. At the start of the next loop iteration, you check to see if it has changed and if it has, print it. If it is still the same value as the previous, don't print it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without the use of a PHP function by taking advantage of MySQL's group_concat function which does exactly what you're looking for:

```
SELECT name, group_concat(`data`) FROM table GROUP BY name;
```

Will return one column with "John" and a second column with "data1,data2". You can then use PHP's explode() function on the second column to get an array containing "data1" and "data2".

Comment: I just read up on `group_concat`, never used it before. Looks very useful and I ran a modified version of your example in phpmyadmin. That's exactly what I'm looking for. So when it returns the results, and I'm inside my `foreach`, would it be something like `explode($row[2])` and then run that through a loop?

Comment: I also found this: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple method:

```
$prevname = "";
while($fetch = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    if( $prevname !== $fetch['name']){
        echo $fetch['name'];
        $prevname = $fetch['name'];
    }
    echo '<br />'. $fetch['data'];
}
```

---

If you want them manageble in an array:

```
$arrayt = array();    while($fetch = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    $array[ $fetch['name'] ][] = $fetch['data'];
}
print_r( $array ); // will print as your prefered output
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. For some reason mixing it into my existing code threw it into an infinite loop, but I'll just debug it and figure out why.