# foreach loop repeating same value

Tags: codeigniter, foreach

I am getting result from two table in my database. Table one has Project name and table two has sub project names under project name this two table is connected by a id.
Now when I output result using foreach by joining two table it is showing showing project name repeatedly as there are  more than one subproject under that repeated project.
I want that the project name will be single and subproject result will loop under the main project name. How to do that?

I amusing codeigniter for development.

my view page:

```
<?php foreach ($reportlist as $project_item): { ?>
<tr>
<td>
<form method='post' action='update_project'>
<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo ($project_item['pid']); ?>' name='pid'>
<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $project_item['pp_id']; ?>' name='pp_id'>
<input type="submit" class="linkButton"  value="<?php echo $project_item['p_name'] ?>">
</form>
</td>

<td>
<form method='post' action='update_subproject'>
<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $project_item['pid']; ?>' name='pid'>
<input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $project_item['pp_id']; ?>' name='pp_id'>
<input type="submit" class="linkButton"  value="<?php echo $project_item['component_name'] ?>" >
</form>
</td> 


    <td><?php echo $project_item['coordinating_authority'] ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $project_item['start_month'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $project_item['target_month'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $project_item['stat_pro'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $project_item['stat_pro'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $project_item['remark_pro'] ?></td>

</tr>
<?php } endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

My cotroller page:

```
  $this->load->model('projsubproj_add_model');
  $data['reportlist'] = $this->projsubproj_add_model->existing_project();
  $this->load->view('PAGE-DESIGN/adminheader');
  $this->load->view('existing_project_view', $data);
  $this->load->view('PAGE-DESIGN/footer');
```

and my model:

```
public function existing_project()
{
{
$this->db->select('project_tab.p_name,
pp_project_tab.pp_id AS pp_id,
pp_project_tab.pid AS pid,
pp_project_tab.ppname AS component_name, 
pp_project_tab.pp_smonth AS start_month,
pp_project_tab.pp_emonth AS target_month,
pp_project_tab.pp_cordn_reqrd AS coordinating_authority,
pp_project_tab.pps_status AS stat_pro,
pp_project_tab.remarks AS remark_pro');
 $this->db->from('project_tab');
        $this->db->join('pp_project_tab', 'pp_project_tab.pid =project_tab.pid');
        //$this->db->join('pp_status_tab', 'pp_status_tab.pp_id = pp_project_tab.pp_id');
        $this->db->order_by('ppname', 'desc');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('project_tab');
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Comment: That’s done via a simple [control break](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break) – you compare the project name of current row to project name of previous row (that you remember in a specific variable, initialized with a value that does not occur in the data, such as an empty string or NULL), and only output when different.

Comment: I tried that but could not figure that out, simply I am new php developer.

Comment: I have about 10 subprojects under single project , so the name is being repeated ten times. When put a break, it only gives one result and rest of the result are vanished. Please help. I can not post the result as I am not allowed to post picture here. Please help someone.

Comment: No one said anything about using the actual `break` keyword … The ”algorithm” I described is pretty simple – compare current value with previous one, and only output when different … that’s _all_ there is to it.

Comment: will you please tell me the way to do that with my code? I meant will you bother for me to give an example?

Comment: Here’s a simple example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24248827/1427878 _Modifying_ that to fit your environment is your task.

Comment: I tried your solution but the result is same. Did you see my view page? How do I apply the idea to my view page or model page? I know it is like rookie , but I am rookie. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution: I just edited my view file for through foreach loop. I made two function to to extract results from  two tables and joined them with condition that if the pid of subproject table matches with the pid of subject table, then echo subproject name and its components inside foreach loop of Project loop.

Here is my code:

$projects is for extracting data from project_tab,
$components is for extracting data from pp_project_tab

```
<?php

foreach ($projects as $project) {

echo $project['p_name'];

foreach ($components as $component) {
    if ($project['pid']==$component['pid']) {
        echo  $component['ppname'] ; 

        }


   }



}
```

?>