# How can I print mysql results to the screen and show only one iteration of a column?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I apologize for the Title, but I could not figure out a better description:

I am selecting from my mysql and it returns the following:

[image]

I am then building a Table in PHP to show it in a table I can print

[image]

My question is how can I show only 1 EVENT, not 3

[image]

Here is the php code:

UPDATE:

```
    $flag = "";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        if( $flag != $row['eventName']){

            $flag = $row['eventName'];

        ?>

        <tr>
            <td align="left" style="margin-left:20px;font-weight: bolder ; "><?php echo $flag ?></td>
            <td align="right"
                style="margin-right:10px; font-weight: bolder;margin-left:20px"><?php echo $row['gender'] ?></td>
            <td align="left"><label style="margin-right:10px;margin-left:20px">
                    <?php echo $row['swimmer_name'] ?>
                </label></td>
            <td align="center"><label class="lane" name="lane"
                                      style="text-align: center;margin-left:20px"><?php echo $row['lane'] ?></label>
            </td>
            <td align="center"><input type="text" style="width:70px;text-align: center;margin-left:20px" class="time"
                                      value="<?php echo $row['time'] ?>" data-mask="00:00:00"></td>
            <td align="center"><span style="margin-right:10px; margin-left:20px" class="place">
                   <?php echo $row['place'] ?>
                </span></td>

            <td align="center"><span style="margin-right:10px; font-weight: bolder;margin-left:20px"
                                     class="score"><?php echo $row['score'] ?></span></td>
            <td align="center"><span style="margin-right:10px; font-weight: bolder;margin-left:20px"
                                     class="score2"><?php echo $row['scoreB'] ?></span></td>
            <td align="center"><span style="text-align: center;margin-left:20px" class="place2">
                    <?php echo $row['placeB'] ?></span></td>
            <td align="center"><input type="text" style="width:70px;text-align: center;margin-left:20px" class="time"
                                      value="<?php echo $row['timeB'] ?>" data-mask="00:00:00"></td>

            <td align="center"><label class="lane" name="laneB"
                                      style="text-align: center;margin-left:20px"><?php echo $row['laneB'] ?></label>
            </td>
            <td align="left"><label style="text-align: center;margin-left:20px">
                    <?php echo $row['swimmer_nameB'] ?>
                </label></td>

        </tr>


    <?php
    }
        else
            {

                $flag == '<td  </td>' ;
            }
    }


    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create variable that stores to contain the EventName of the prior loops event..  Before you write out the event name check to see if the current record matches the variable.  If it doesn't write out the name and update the variable.  If it does don't write anything out.  This assumes events are "SORTED" in the query by event name.  (your's isn't presently)  I'd sort by name and lane perhaps.

Comment: Can u give me a little more help?

Comment: Here's an example of PHP code using control break logic from a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248778/mysql-return-first-column-once-and-all-corresponding-column-data)  Look at Martijn's answer as it shows the control break logic. or use break and continue http://www.afterhoursprogramming.com/tutorial/PHP/Break-and-Continue/

Comment: I tried it and it works halfway. 
I can't figure out how to add empty eventname so it shows:

'aaa   xxx
         yyy
         zzz
bbb   xxx
         yyy'
         zzz

Comment: Update  your question with the new code set we'll figure it out from there.

Comment: Can you share your query?

Comment: mysqli_select_db($connect, "hs_swim");
    $results = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT event_id, eventName, gender, swimmer_name, lane,time,place,score,scoreB, placeB, timeB,laneB, swimmer_nameB FROM swimMeetData order by event_id");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a php expert; but this may be one way...

```
$flag = "";
$display = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    if( $flag != $row['eventName']){
        $flag = $row['eventName'];
        $display=$flag;
    else
        $display="";
?>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" style="margin-left:20px;font-weight: bolder ; "><?php echo $display?></td>

        <td align="right"
            style="margin-right:10px; font-weight: bolder;margin-left:20px"><?php echo $row['gender'] ?></td>
        <td align="left"><label style="margin-right:10px;margin-left:20px">
                <?php echo $row['swimmer_name'] ?>
            </label></td>
        <td align="center"><label class="lane" name="lane"
                                  style="text-align: center;margin-left:20px"><?php echo $row['lane'] ?></label>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" style="width:70px;text-align: center;margin-left:20px" class="time"
                                  value="<?php echo $row['time'] ?>" data-mask="00:00:00"></td>
        <td align="center"><span style="margin-right:10px; margin-left:20px" class="place">
               <?php echo $row['place'] ?>
            </span></td>

        <td align="center"><span style="margin-right:10px; font-weight: bolder;margin-left:20px"
                                 class="score"><?php echo $row['score'] ?></span></td>
        <td align="center"><span style="margin-right:10px; font-weight: bolder;margin-left:20px"
                                 class="score2"><?php echo $row['scoreB'] ?></span></td>
        <td align="center"><span style="text-align: center;margin-left:20px" class="place2">
                <?php echo $row['placeB'] ?></span></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" style="width:70px;text-align: center;margin-left:20px" class="time"
                                  value="<?php echo $row['timeB'] ?>" data-mask="00:00:00"></td>

        <td align="center"><label class="lane" name="laneB"
                                  style="text-align: center;margin-left:20px"><?php echo $row['laneB'] ?></label>
        </td>
        <td align="left"><label style="text-align: center;margin-left:20px">
                <?php echo $row['swimmer_nameB'] ?>
            </label></td>

    </tr>


<?php
}
    else
        {

            $flag == '<td  </td>' ;
        }
}


?>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked great. I made a minor tweet and it solved the problem
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$flag = "";
$display = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    if ($flag != $row['eventName']) {
        $flag = $row['eventName'];
        $display = $flag;
    }
    else
        $display = ""; ?>
     <tr>
         <td align="left" style="margin-left:20px;font-weight: bolder ; "><?php echo $display ?></td>
        <td align="right"
            style="margin-right:10px; font-weight: bolder;margin-left:20px"><?php echo $row['gender'] ?></td>
        <td align="left"><label style="margin-right:10px;margin-left:20px">
                <?php echo $row['swimmer_name'] ?>
            </label></td>
        <td align="center"><label class="lane" name="lane"
                                  style="text-align: center;margin-left:20px"><?php echo $row['lane'] ?></label>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" style="width:70px;text-align: center;margin-left:20px" class="time"
                                  value="<?php echo $row['time'] ?>" data-mask="00:00:00"></td>
        <td align="center"><span style="margin-right:10px; margin-left:20px" class="place">
           <?php echo $row['place'] ?>
        </span></td>

        <td align="center"><span style="margin-right:10px; font-weight: bolder;margin-left:20px"
                                 class="score"><?php echo $row['score'] ?></span></td>
        <td align="center"><span style="margin-right:10px; font-weight: bolder;margin-left:20px"
                                 class="score2"><?php echo $row['scoreB'] ?></span></td>
        <td align="center"><span style="text-align: center;margin-left:20px" class="place2">
            <?php echo $row['placeB'] ?></span></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" style="width:70px;text-align: center;margin-left:20px" class="time"
                                  value="<?php echo $row['timeB'] ?>" data-mask="00:00:00"></td>

        <td align="center"><label class="lane" name="laneB"
                                  style="text-align: center;margin-left:20px"><?php echo $row['laneB'] ?></label>
        </td>
        <td align="left"><label style="text-align: center;margin-left:20px">
                <?php echo $row['swimmer_nameB'] ?>
            </label></td>

        </tr>


    <?php

}
```